# how do i access the To access the Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net, membership

i found an article that says:

"To access the Web Site Administration Tool, on the Website menu, click ASP.Net Configuration."

I dont see a Website menu in visual studio 2008 when i am looking at my asp.net mvc solution.

Is there any other way i can setup roles with asp.net membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can also setup Roles with asp.net membership using the web.config file, and actually defining the users/roles that are available.

As far as why you aren't seeing the menu:
Are you in a website, or a project.  Try converting your project to a web project, and see if the menu appears for you then.

Answer (score 1):

in your visual studio

project menu -- asp.net configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try http://blogs.msdn.com/rahulso/archive/2006/03/09/how-to-use-web-site-administration-tool-without-installing-vs-2005.aspx, altough this technique is not supported by microsoft.

Comment: i have visual studio 2008, i just dont see the menu

Comment: It's basically the same interface...but make sure, you have the web project selected (and not an additional library) and select Project -> ASP.NET configuration